Bound of Joint Spectral Radius of Matrix plus Identity
Given a Matrix $A$ with spectral radius $\rho(A)$, we can prove that $\rho(A+I)\leq\rho(A)+1$. This is the case, since the spectral radius is defined as $\rho(A)=\max{|\lambda_i|}$ and the eigenvalues of $A+I$ are $\lambda_i+1$, with $\lambda_i$ being $A$'s eigenvalues. So: $|\lambda_i+1| \leq |\lambda_i|+1$ and therefore follows the above statement about the spectral radius.
Now, the spectral radius can also be defined as a limit: $\rho(A)=\lim_{k\to\infty} ||A^k||^{1/k}$

Is it possible to prove a similar result starting from this definition of the spectral radius?

Related to this is the definition of the joint spectral radius: $\tilde\rho(\mathcal{A}) = \lim_{k\to\infty} \max\{ ||A_{i_1}A_{i_2}\dots A_{i_k}||^{1/k}, A_{i}\in\mathcal{A}  \}$ for a finite set $\mathcal{A}$.
Intuitively, a similar argument as in the first case should hold: Adding the identity matrix to each $A_i$ should not increase the joint spectral radius by more than one, that is
\begin{equation}
\tilde\rho(\tilde{\mathcal{A}})=\lim_{k\to\infty} \max\{ ||(I+A_{i_1})(I+A_{i_2})\dots (I+A_{i_k})||^{1/k}, A_{i}\in\mathcal{A}  \} \leq\tilde\rho(\mathcal{A}) + 1.
\end{equation}

Is that true and how can I prove it?

I tried expanding the term inside the norm and using norm-inequalities, however that seems like a dead end. My struggle to find a prove for that property is also linked to not being a able to find an answer to question 1, as the form is very similar to the definition of the joint spectral radius.

For part 1, you can use the fact that
$$
|(I + A)^k| \leq (1 + |A|)^k,
$$
which can be shown with a combination of the binomial theorem, the triangle inequality, and submultiplicativity (i.e. the fact that $|AB| \leq |A|,|B|$).

Actually, never mind about the binomial theorem. We have
$$
|(I + A)^k| \leq |I + A|^k \leq (|I| + |A|)^k = (1 + |A|)^k
$$

@BenGrossmann But that just gives $\rho(I+A) \leq 1+||A||$, right? That's different from $\rho(I+A) \leq 1+\rho(A)$

You're right, my mistake
